# Python3.9 with module "re" and "check_output" when object type is None

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, methods, module

I'll trying to wite a program that search a pattern to find when a check_output of an ifconfig was given. So I define a function, in a condition where the "interface" has got a MAC, I can go ahead, while if there's no MAC address and the object type is None, I can't go ahead with the else condition. Please, what I'm wrong?

```
def get_current_mac(interface):

    pattern = r"([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}"
    ifconfig_result = (check_output(["ifconfig", interface])).decode('utf-8')
    mac_address_result = (re.search(pattern, ifconfig_result).group())
    if mac_address_result:
    
        print("Current MAC = " + mac_address_result)

    else:
        print ('No MAC')
```

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

RG

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Can you share the code for check_output() and sample value for interface?

Comment: @AndyKnight It looks like it's the standard `subprocess.check_output()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `.group()` on `None`. You have to call that in the `if`.

```
def get_current_mac(interface):
    pattern = r"([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}"
    ifconfig_result = check_output(["ifconfig", interface]).decode('utf-8')
    mac_address_result = re.search(pattern, ifconfig_result)
    if mac_address_result:
        print("Current MAC = " + mac_address_result.group())
    else:
        print ('No MAC')
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, it's warking like a charm, my bad.